# Is there a way to redirect Classic ASP errors differently from .NET errors?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic

I've got a hybrid .NET and classic ASP site. Error handling in .NET is done with the `Application_Error` event, with custom handling for 500 errors. I'd like to handle errors in Classic ASP by routing to a custom ASP page, but I can't find any way to do this other than an entry like this in web.config:

```
<error statusCode="500" path="/error500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

But this will route **all** 500 errors, not just the ones caused by Classic ASP pages. So the question is: can I reroute just the Classic ASP errors while letting .NET errors be handled by .NET code?

Comment: see this answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264068/classic-asp-capture-errors

Comment: `<error statusCode="500.100" path="/error500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />`

Comment: @VMV: That worked perfectly, thanks. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it. Is there documentation somewhere about this `500.100` status code. Is that a Microsoft specific extension to HTTP to distinguish classic ASP errors from other 500 errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<error statusCode="500.100" path="/error500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />` in web.config. See all IIS response codes this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891/en

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.